# When I used Chinese UITableview cell will be color blended

Tags: uikit

When I enable my simulator debug option "Color blended laysers"
Then showing the different result as follow:

Sorry that I can not post images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLRqh.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOQso.jpg

Answer (score 2):

It looks like labels with Chinese characters will have an extra sublayer (not subviews).

When I add two `UILabel`s to a view, one with English characters and one with Chinese, there are slightly different hierarchies.

`0x7fd3b972c020` is the `UILabel` with English characters:

```
(lldb) po [[0x7fd3b972c020 layer] sublayers]
 nil
(lldb) po [0x7fd3b972c020 layer]
<_UILabelLayer:0x7fd3b972c2b0; position = CGPoint (187.5 333.75); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 133 20.5); delegate = <UILabel: 0x7fd3b972c020; frame = (121 323.5; 133 20.5); text = 'This is just a test.'; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd3b972c2b0>>; contents = <CABackingStore 0x7fd3bb0e1530 (buffer [266 41] BGRX8888)>; opaque = YES; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; rasterizationScale = 2; contentsScale = 2>
```

`0x7fd3b95208f0` is the `UILabel` with Chinese characters:

```
(lldb) po [[0x7fd3b95208f0 layer] sublayers]
<CALayerArray 0x7fd3bb0e0c90>(
<_UILabelContentLayer:0x7fd3bb0e0a60; position = CGPoint (68.25 11); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 140.5 29); contents = <CABackingStore 0x7fd3bb0e1180 (buffer [281 58] BGRA8888)>; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; rasterizationScale = 2; contentsScale = 2>
)


(lldb) po [0x7fd3b95208f0 layer]
<_UILabelLayer:0x7fd3b950ba70; position = CGPoint (187.5 361.75); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 136 20.5); delegate = <UILabel: 0x7fd3b95208f0; frame = (119.5 351.5; 136 20.5); text = '这只是一个测试。'; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd3b950ba70>>; sublayers = (<_UILabelContentLayer: 0x7fd3bb0e0a60>); opaque = YES; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; rasterizationScale = 2; contentsScale = 2>
```

Each of the views have `opaque` enabled with white background colors.

Comment: Is there a solution for Chinese characters being red? Or it has to stay red?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Chinese characters for red:

`label.layer.maskToBounds = true`

Comment: Typo, missing 's':  label.layer.masksToBounds = true