# UILabel is marked as red when `Color Blended Layers` is selected

Tags: uitableview, uilabel, ios-simulator

I have some UILabels whose `backgroundColor` are white or red, and opaque are all YES.

But when the `Color Blended Layers` option is selected in Simulator, these UILabels are marked as red instead of green.

What else options can cause these?

My code is as followed:

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        self.senderNameLabel = [UILabel mt_labelWithFont:FONT(17) andColor:COLOR_NAV_TITLE];
        self.senderNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.senderNameLabel];

        self.actionTextLabel = [UILabel mt_labelWithFont:FONT(15) andColor:COLOR_NAV_TITLE];
        self.actionTextLabel.numberOfLines = 5;
        self.actionTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.actionTextLabel];

        self.notifyDateLabel = [UILabel mt_labelWithFont:FONT(12) andColor:COLOR_NAV_TITLE];
        self.notifyDateLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.notifyDateLabel];

        [self setLayoutConstraints];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setLayoutConstraints {
    CGFloat offsetX = 70;
    CGFloat offsetY = 15;
    CGFloat maxWidth = SCALE_WITH_RATIO(180);
    [self.senderNameLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
      make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(offsetX);
      make.top.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(offsetY);
      make.width.mas_lessThanOrEqualTo(maxWidth);
    }];

    offsetY = 12.5;
    maxWidth = SCALE_WITH_RATIO(180);
    [self.actionTextLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
      make.top.equalTo(self.senderNameLabel.mas_bottom).offset(offsetY);
      make.left.equalTo(self.senderNameLabel);
      make.width.mas_lessThanOrEqualTo(maxWidth);
    }];

    offsetY = 10;
    CGFloat bottomOffsetY = -15;
    [self.notifyDateLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
      make.top.equalTo(self.actionTextLabel.mas_bottom).offset(offsetY);
      make.left.equalTo(self.senderNameLabel);
      make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(bottomOffsetY);
    }];
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];

    self.senderNameLabel.text = nil;
    self.actionTextLabel.text = nil;
    self.notifyDateLabel.text = nil;
}

- (void)updateWithMessageModel:(MTUserMessageModel *)model {
    self.senderNameLabel.text = model.senderName;
    self.actionTextLabel.text = model.actionText;
    self.notifyDateLabel.text = model.notifyDate;
}
```

The helper method for `UILabel` generation is as follow:

```
+ (UILabel *)mt_labelWithFont:(UIFont *)font andColor:(UIColor *)color {
    UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
    label.font = font;
    label.textColor = color;
    return label;
}
```

The snapshot from simulator is as follow
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just find a solution:

```
titleLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Then it become green again.

---

I found the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759796/when-i-used-chinese-uitableview-cell-will-be-color-blended) that says when displaying Chinese `UILabel` will have an extra sublayer.

Say if you have a UILabel instance called `titleLabel`. Setting text with Chinese or English, and check the sublayers using debug command:

```
po [[titleLabel layer] sublayers]
```

Comment: @xi.lin Is there a solution after all? Or Chinese characters have to stay in red?

Comment: @JoeHuang I think currently it is how the UILabel works. Maybe you can tried some other way to show text. I didn't make experiments on core text and something else.

Comment: @xi.lin nice finding, great!