# Is it possible to make UILabel with non-English characters green when Color Blended Layer is enabled?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uilabel, core-graphics

I have a table view with custom cells and I try to optimize it by making all subviews inside the cells in green color when `Color Blended Layer` is checked in the simulator.

When the background of an `UILabel` in the cell is set to white:

```
let title = UILabel()
contentView.addSubview(title)
title.background = UIColor.whiteColor()
title.text = "Hi, how are you?"
```

This UILabel subview will become green color in the simulator, which is good. However, if I change the text to some Chinese:

```
title.text = "你好"
```

The UILabel subview will become red. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759796/when-i-used-chinese-uitableview-cell-will-be-color-blended) provides some explanation about the situation. Is there actually a solution for this?

Comment: Why it's important for you to have the same color when "Color Blended Layer" is enabled in the simulator?

Comment: To improve scrolling performance as some other advised in other question. I do find better performance if I only have English labels.

Comment: I think you just ask a wrong question. What you need is how to get better performance for your tableview but not `non-English characters green when Color Blended Layer is enabled`. 
When your UILabel with non-English characters green when color blended layer is enabled, its not mean your tableview performance is better.

Comment: @DinhNhat Yes, understood. I have been trying to optimize the performance from many perspectives. I am not sure if making it all green in this case would help a bit or nothing at all, but I am trying to explore all possibilities and learn. This is just one of the directions.

Comment: @JoeHuang i have one small concept try that

Comment: @JoeHuang my code helps for you .?

Comment: @KishoreKumar sorry, no... I don't quite understand your answer.

Comment: @JoeHuang is it possible to get string first letter for eg "Hi how are you", in that take only H.and compare with my array ,if it is chinese are some other word then work on with else part .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CATextLayer` instead of `UILabel`. And don't forget to set its `opaque` property to `true`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // You should definitely put layer handling logic into 
        // UITableViewCell subclass. I'm omitting it for clarity
    let layer = cell.contentView.layer

    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.string = "你好"
    textLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)
    textLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 25)
    textLayer.opaque = true

    layer.addSublayer(textLayer)

    return cell
}
```

**UPD:** If a black background is not what you are looking for, a problem becomes a bit trickier, but yet solvable.

All you need is to inject two lines of code into drawing mechanism. There are two ways to achieve this:

- to use a `delegate` of a `CALayer` or
- to make a subclass of `CATextLayer`.

In our case I believe the latter is preferable. So instead of `CATextLayer` in the example below use this class:

```
class OpaqueTextLayerWithCustomizableBackgroundColor: CATextLayer {
    override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {
        if let color = backgroundColor {
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, color)
            CGContextFillRect(ctx, bounds);
        }
        super.drawInContext(ctx)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested and it works. However, when setting `opaque` to true, the background becomes black and ignores `textLayer.backgroundColor` setting (always black no matter how). Any workaround for this? I can't use the black background.

Comment: well... at least it's a way to solve the original question which didn't mention about background color. If you know any further info that might help, just let me know. I will reward the credit to you. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeHuang, I've updated the answer with additional info you were looking for.

Comment: By the way, I also add one line `titleLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` to make the characters look normal in Retina Display.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, three steps in XIB (personal preference), or in code.

> 1. set opaque = YES
> 2. backgroundColor = a solid color
> 3. clipsToBound = YES

then non english UILabel will render-pass once, as green.

Comment: Thank you! The clipsToBounds=YES was the thing I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say this is the internal implementation of Apple. And we shouldn't / (probably) can't fiddle with it. After all, the 'colors' you see is only the representation of the structure of the layers. The answer on the question you attached is a good explanation.

I would suggest that don't plan any premature optimizations. After all, even if you do feel performance increase, the 'Color Blended Layer' is ugly and cannot be applied for real devices. Or simply try not to pay attention to it!

Edit:

Here is a screenshot from Apple's Simulator, if Apple can live with that, you can live with it too!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Check your textlayer.string first letter is English or some other**

```
 NSMutableArray*arrAlphabets;
    arrAlphabets=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",nil]]
```

Then Inside Tableview cell for row at indexpath method:

```
NSString *str=[textlayer.string substringToIndex:1];
if(str isEqualToString:arrAlphabets)   //use for loop to run arralphabets
{
    //do your code to maintail the layer color .
}
```

Hope this concept helps you :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could check for monospace characters (western) versus proportional ones (Chinese) depending on the font used.

Monospace characters are 8-bit where proportional ones are 16-bit. I'm at a loss of how Swift could check for byte sizes, so I can't provide any code.

Apple's Swift programming guide can help. Check the section titled: Unicode Representations of Strings.

Comment: Please provide more detail